# ASP .Net MVC how to force close session from external website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, crm

I am interested to close session of a user from an external website (i.e. CRM).
In case of a user complains about another user, or a user is cheating in the website A, I want to be able to close forcibly his session from a website B ( the CRM).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from Website B.  You will need to write in functionality into Website A that Website B can call in order to kick the user out.

Probably the simplest way would be to have a field on your user record on Website A which indicates whether the user is active, and Website A checks periodically to ensure that flag is still valid.  If not, sign the user out.